# QT Creator : lines that draw boundaries of block

Tags: qt-creator

Please help to (fix bug) config QT Creator(6.0.2). I need to see the borders of C++ blocks such as:

```
if(condition){
|    ------
|    ------
|    ------
|    ------
|    a lot of code
|    ------
}
```

Like this:

[image]

However, there are no lines in QT Creator:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this feature exists in Qt Creator but you have some other (activated by default) that highlights matching parentheses, etc... It should be sufficient. If it really annoys you that much, maybe you will have to use another editor.

Comment: Anyway, you called it a bug but it isn't a bug at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Creator 9.0.0-beta1
qt tech support says that this version have this option

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator has `Visualize whitespace` option like this.

[image]

Result.

[image]

Comment: It isn't what OP was asking for